# Get substring between "\" where multiple "\"

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, substring, trim

Found this solution to get substring after slash () character

```
DECLARE @st1 varchar(10)
SET @st1 = 'MYTEST\aftercompare'
SELECT @st1
,SUBSTRING(@st1, CHARINDEX('\', @st1) + 1, LEN(@st1))
```

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/5c3a5e2c-54fc-43dd-b12c-1a1f6784d7d8/tsql-get-substring-after-slash-character

But is there a way to get substring after second slash or even more?

```
DECLARE @st1 varchar(50)
--Added more slashes
SET @st1 = 'MYTEST\aftercompare\slash2\slash3\slash4'
SELECT @st1
--This part would need some work
--,SUBSTRING(@st1, CHARINDEX('\', @st1) + 1, LEN(@st1))
```

And getting only the substring between the slashes.

Values: [1] "aftercompare" - [2] "slash2" - [3] "slash3" - [4] "slash4"

Comment: Why do you want to do this in T-SQL? Your client language will be much, much, much more efficient at this.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Total agreement +1

Comment: Working with a table where the column information is like that format:
"8:00-10:00 \ Male \ 4 Division \ Room1"
"10:00-12:00 \ Female \ 8 Division \ Room2"

And do not have access to the original insert.
And want to create dimensions for each scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want to do it in TSQL, see below.

[I've gamed SQL Fiddle into showing it working](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/935c5/14), ignore the CROSS JOIN's in the fiddle, they just get around SQLFiddle's limitation over DECLARE.

```
DECLARE @s varchar(8000);
DECLARE @sep char;

SET @s = 'MYTEST\aftercompare\slash2\slash3\slash4';
SET @sep = '\';

WITH [splits] AS (
    SELECT
        0 [index],
        CHARINDEX(@sep, @s) [pos],
        0 [lastPos]
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        [index] + 1,
        CHARINDEX(@sep, @s, [pos] + 1),
        [pos]
    FROM [splits]
    WHERE
        [pos] > 0)
SELECT
    [index],
    SUBSTRING(
        @s,
        [lastPos] + 1,
        CASE WHEN [pos] = 0
            THEN 8000
            ELSE [pos] - [lastPos] - 1
        END) [value]
FROM [splits];
```

gives the result

```
INDEX   VALUE 
0       MYTEST 
1       aftercompare 
2       slash2 
3       slash3 
4       slash4
```

---

In a SQL 2005 database where I couldn't use table value parameters I made .Net CLR `Split` to compose the normal .Net `Split` function. String manipulation is simpler and faster with the right tools.

---

If required, [here is a `NVarChar(MAX)` version.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f784a/4)

```
DECLARE @s nvarchar(max);
DECLARE @sep nchar;

SET @s = N'MYTEST\aftercompare\slash2\slash3\slash4';
SET @sep = N'\';

WITH [splits] AS (
    SELECT
        CAST(0 AS bigint) [index],
        CHARINDEX(@sep, @s) [pos],
        CAST(0 AS bigint) [lastPos]
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        [index] + 1,
        CHARINDEX(@sep, @s, [pos] + 1),
        [pos]
    FROM [splits]
    WHERE
        [pos] > 0)
SELECT
    [index],
    SUBSTRING(
        @s,
        [lastPos] + 1,
        CASE WHEN [pos] = 0
            THEN 2147483647
            ELSE [pos] - [lastPos] - 1
        END) value
FROM [splits];
```

Comment: Nice solution, now I just need to update it towards my tables. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could use this table valued function to return a table with individual rows for each splitted result:

```
    ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[Split]
    (
        @sString nvarchar(2000),
        @cDelimiter nchar(1)
    )
    RETURNS 
    @TblSplits TABLE 
    (
        SplitText nvarchar(2000)
    )
    AS
    BEGIN
        if @sString is null return
        declare @iStart int,
                @iPos int
        if substring( @sString, 1, 1 ) = @cDelimiter 
        begin
            set @iStart = 2
            insert into @TblSplits
            values( null )
        end
        else 
            set @iStart = 1
        while 1=1
        begin
            set @iPos = charindex( @cDelimiter, @sString, @iStart )
            if @iPos = 0
                set @iPos = len( @sString )+1
            if @iPos - @iStart > 0          
                insert into @TblSplits
                values  ( substring( @sString, @iStart, @iPos-@iStart ))
            else
                insert into @TblSplits
                values( null )
            set @iStart = @iPos+1
            if @iStart > len( @sString ) 
                break
        end

        DELETE @TblSplits WHERE SplitText IS NULL;

        RETURN
    END
```

with this you can call the function like this:

```
        DECLARE @st1 nvarchar(50)
        --Added more slashes
        SET @st1 = 'MYTEST\aftercompare\slash2\slash3\slash4'
        SELECT @st1

        SELECT * from dbo.Split(@st1,N'\');
```